# Notification system is not working properly JSON/PHP

Tags: php, mysql, json, ajax, notifications

I am trying to make notification bell with count of unread notifications. I am using Javascript with the help of php to fetch the data from the mysqli table and to return it as JSON type, but I dont know where is the problem, I dont receive any output.

The only working thing here is that when I click on the bell icon, it is changing my comment_status from 0 to 1.

Thank you!

Here is my code:

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


 function load_unseen_notification(view = '')
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"./include/fetch_messages.php",
   method:"POST",
   data:{view:view},
   dataType: "json",
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('.dropdown-menu').html(data.notification);

    if(data.unseen_notification > 0)
    {
     $('.count').html(data["unseen_notification"]);
    }

   }
  });
 }

 load_unseen_notification();

 $(document).on('click', '.dropdown-toggle', function(){
  $('.count').html('');
  load_unseen_notification('yes');
 });

});
```

My fetch_messages.php file:

```
<?php include 'connect.php'; ?>
<?php
//fetch_messages.php;
if(isset($_POST["view"]))
{
  echo "string";

 if($_POST["view"] != '')
 {
  $update_query = "UPDATE comments SET comment_status=1 WHERE comment_status=0";
  mysqli_query($conn, $update_query);
 }
 $query = "SELECT * FROM comments ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 5";
 $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
 $output = '';

 if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
 {
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
   $output .= '
   <li>
    <a href="#">
     <strong>'.$row["user_commented"].'</strong><br />
     <small><em>'.$row["comment"].'</em></small>
    </a>
   </li>
   <li class="divider"></li>
   ';
  }
 }
 else
 {
  $output .= '<li><a href="#" class="text-bold text-italic">No Notification Found</a></li>';
 }

 $query_1 = "SELECT * FROM comments WHERE comment_status=1";
 $result_1 = mysqli_query($conn, $query_1);
 $count = mysqli_num_rows($result_1);
 $data = array(
  'notification'   => $output,
  'unseen_notification' => $count
 );

 echo json_encode($data);
}
?>
```

And my html where is my output will be:

```
<ul >
  <li class="dropdown">
   <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"><span class="label label-pill label-danger count" style="border-radius:10px;"></span> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-envelope" style="font-size:18px;"></span></a>
   <ul class="dropdown-menu">...</ul>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

Comment: show what you are getting on ajax call

Comment: i put console.log(data); in success function but nothing

Comment: Go check what the request gets answered with using the network panel of your browser dev tools then. Also, please go read up on what the basics of debugging are in such an environment - SO is not the place to explain that over and over again.

Comment: Maybe I have found the error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected token s in JSON at position 0", but how can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I found it, I had a line with "echo 'string'; " I remove it and everything is fine now! Thanks for the guide!